# Boxes are too small in properties view

Tags: properties, anylogic

In the properties view the boxes keep appearing really small, to the point where I can't see what's in them. In the image it is happening in front of the delay time but it is a general problem and whenever there are boxes to write in, this happens. I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and I've already reinstalled Anylogic but this error keeps on appearing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X71e4.png)

Comment: i think anylogic gave up on linux and mac.. the amount of interface bugs of this kind is just too much

Comment: might not be wrong @Felipe. Not least since they are going for web-based GUI for AL9 anyway, when all this hopefully is a thing of the past...

Comment: I kind of thought that @Felipe but I did not see anyone with this issue anywhere so I figured it was something on my side

Comment: i have this kind of issue with the last version of Mac OS Big Sur.... it's just very painful

Comment: Do you know if it is just a graphical problem or are there more serious issues about it? I'm new to Anylogic, started using it for a college project

Comment: mostly graphical...